# Resample with custom month-end frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, frequency

I'm looking for an equivalent specification to `W-MON` (weekly, ending Monday) for monthly data.

Specifically, I have a pandas data frame of daily data, and I want to only take monthly observations, starting with the most recent date and going back monthly.

So if today is 17/06/2016, my date index would be 17/06/2016, 17/05/2016, 17/04/2016... etc.

Right now I can only find month-start and month-end as specifications for df.asfreq().

Thanks.

Comment: What about anchoring them to the start of the month, then adding a timedelta of the appropriate days? (Not quite sure that'd work with months that don't have the required number of days though...)

Comment: What is your desired output when today is 31 Jan?
Clearly you can't have 31 Feb

Answer (score 0):

You can create the relevant dates using `relativedelta` and select using `.loc[]`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
```

Using daily sample data:

```
stock_data = DataReader('FB', 'yahoo', datetime(2013, 1, 1), datetime.today()).resample('D').fillna(method='ffill')['Open']
```

and a month end date to show how `relativedelta` treats this case:

```
today = date(2016, 1, 31)
```

Create the sequence of dates:

```
n_months = 30
dates = [today - relativedelta(years=m // 12, months=m % 12) for m in range(n_months)]
```

to get:

```
stock_data.loc[dates]

Date
2016-01-31    108.989998
2015-12-31    106.000000
2015-11-30    105.839996
2015-10-31    104.510002
2015-09-30     88.440002
2015-08-31     90.599998
2015-07-31     94.949997
2015-06-30     86.599998
2015-05-31     79.949997
2015-04-30     80.010002
2015-03-31     82.900002
2015-02-28     80.680000
2015-01-31     78.000000
2014-12-31     79.540001
2014-11-30     77.669998
2014-10-31     74.930000
2014-09-30     79.349998
2014-08-31     74.300003
2014-07-31     74.000000
2014-06-30     67.459999
2014-05-31     63.950001
2014-04-30     57.580002
2014-03-31     60.779999
2014-02-28     69.470001
2014-01-31     60.470001
2013-12-31     54.119999
2013-11-30     46.750000
2013-10-31     47.160000
2013-09-30     50.139999
2013-08-31     42.020000
Name: Open, dtype: float64
```